# how to login with partial view and ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I use ajax in my MVC application. When I post data with ajax to the controller,  the controller returns a partial view back to the view correctly, but when I use   `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` to make user log in, the controller returns the whole page instead of the partial view. So, I'll end up having a page inside another which is not good.

Here is ajax and controller:

```js
function LoginUser() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var url = '/UserManagement/LoginUser/';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            "username": username.value,
            "password": password.value
        }, //parameters go here in object literal form
        type: 'Post',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === "") {
                alert('user not found');
            } else {
                $('#divUser').html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function () { alert('Error'); }
    });
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginUser(string username, string password)
{
    var cus = customer.GetCustomerByUserNameAndPassWord(username, password);
    if (cus != null && cus.IsActive)
    {
        //FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(cus.ID.ToString(), false);
        //if uncomment this controller send whole page instead of partialview
        return PartialView("ShowUsermanagementView",true);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's what `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` does. It redirect to a page. You shouldn't use it if you want to use ajax and partial views.

Comment: what should I use instead of that?

Comment: What's wrong with returning the partial view? What do you need to achieve? By the way, use meaningful names for your objects and variables. Your entity should be called `customers` and your variable should be called `customer` instead of `cus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem by using

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(cus.ID.ToString(), false);
```